# Microsoft Azure WebApp scaling to 10 instance on S2

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I am using Azure Web app for hosting background jobs. I have Scale out plan to increase instance count by 1 if CPU or memory utilization goes above 85% and scale down if it is less than 65%. Now interesting part is that when my web app is on S2, web app goes to 10 instance while if I scale it up to S3, the instance count remains to 1 instance.
I am confused as it doesnt add up. If I keep my web app on S3, CPU and memory utilization remains below 50%.

Additional details

1. Job is subscriber to Azure Service bus. It keep watch on a service bus queue
2. Azure SDK - latest for dotnet core

Comment: What is your use case that causes the spike in utilization? are you testing consistently on both S2 and S3.  What triggers your web job?  what version of the Azure SDK are you using?